# Intuition of embedding set theory as pointed graphs into type theory

Tags: set-theory, type-theory

I'm reading this SEP on [type theory](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/type-theory/) and I am confusd in the following part:

> How can we explain the notion of sets in terms of types? There is an elegant solution, due to A. Miquel which complements the previous works by P. Aczel (1978) and which has also the advantage of explaining non necessarily well-founded sets a la Finsler. One simplys interprets a set as a pointed graph (where the arrow in the graph represents the membership relation). This is conventiently represented in type theory, **a point graph** being simply given by a type $A$ and a pair of elements $$a: A , R : A \to A \to o$$...

Later the notion of bisimulation is used to define equivalence of sets , and then the membership relation.

Could someone explain what Sets have to do with pointed graphs?

Comment: Draw the membership graphs. For example, $\emptyset$ is $\bullet$, $\{ \emptyset \}$ is $\bullet - \bullet$, $\{ \{ \emptyset \} \}$ is $\bullet - \bullet - \bullet$...